# How can I insert an <option> into a <select> mutiple element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I insert an `<option>` into a `<select>` (multiple) element using jQuery?

(I don't want to use select here. I want to use the element's ID so that I can use the same function for multiple elements.)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('#elementsID').append('<option>my new option</option>');
```

UPDATE

to insert after option that lolks like `<option value="value1">option with value1</option>` use:

```
var newOption = $('<option value="newOpt">my new option</option>');
newOption.insertAfter('#elementsID option[value="value1"]');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Append will work but I want to insert in between. Can you please tell me how can I do same

Comment: It works. Great. Thank you very much. One more small question. How can i get length and index of select element. Thanks

Comment: @Royal, you can get length by using `$('#elementsID').length()`. I didn't understand what you meant by "index of select element". Can you explain, please?

Comment: Oh sorry selected item's index.

Comment: @Royal, try `$('#elementsID').prop('selectedIndex')`.

Answer (score 3):

To **append** an option:

```
$('#colors').append('<option>red</option>');
```

To **insert** an option before or after another option:

```
$('<option>blue</option>').insertBefore("#colors option:contains('red')");
$('<option>yellow</option>').insertAfter("#colors option:contains('blue')");
```

To **replace** an option with another option:

```
$("#colors option:contains('blue')").replaceWith("<option>pink</option>");
```

To **replace all** options:

```
$('#colors')
   .html("<option>green</option>" +
         "<option>orange</option>" +
         "<option>violet</option>");
```

Comment: probably because you are replacing the entire list instead of inserting an option as originally asked. **multiple** was referring to `<select id="foo" name="foo" multiple="multiple">`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Example:

```
var myOption = $("<option value='Option X'>X</option>");
$("#selectId").append(myOption);
```

If you want to insert items in between one another, you can use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) or [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
myOption.insertAfter("$#idOfItemIWantToInsertAfter");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Append will work but I want to insert in between. Can you please tell me how can I do

Comment: Can you please give me one example. How can i pass element id and index as "idOfItemIWantToInsertAfter"